# React Router Links aiming to specific components

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Let's say I have an app utilizing `react-router-dom`

```
App.js
```

```
class App extends Component {
   render() {
      return (
        <Fragment>
          <Switch location={location}>
            <Route exact path="/" component={LoginPage} />
            <Route loggedIn={loggedIn} path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} location={location} />
          </Switch>
        </Fragment>
      )
   }
}
```

Then inside my Dashboard component I have a Link, but I want the Link to only update my ChatConversation component based on a match of the `match.params.id`

```
Dashboard.js
```

```
<Fragment>
  <Left>
    <SettingsMenu />
    <ConversationsContainer />
  </Left>
  <Right>
    <Route path="/dashboard/conversations/:id" component={ChatConversation} />
  </Right>
</Fragment>
```

Is there a way to make it so only my component `ChatConversation` updates and it doesn't update the whole app component located within the switch of my `App.js`?

```
ChatConversation.js
```

```
<Fragment>
  Conversation ID: {match.params.id}
</Fragment>
```

Comment: Can you add your code to codesandbox so that I can check